# How to create 100000 entries in mongodb at a time?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, mongoengine

While creating 100000 (that's **One Hundred Thousand**) entires at a time, it crashes. My DB is something like this:

```
EmbDoc(EmbeddedDocument):
    id = StringField(required=True, primary_key=True)
    field_one = StringField()
    ...

MyDoc(Document):
    emb_doc_list = EmbeddedDcoumentListField(EmbDoc)
    total_emb_doc = IntField()
    ...
```

Now I want each of MyDoc to have upto 100 EmbDoc and if it reaches 100, I create another MyDoc.(My actual data is present in EmbDoc).
In order to do this, I query MyDocs and find the existing MyDoc which has less than 100 entires and add an entry.

This logic works just fine if I try to create 1000 entires(but takes around 40 second on local machine). But when I try to add large data at a time, it fails miserably.

Any idea on how to solve this problem will be helpful.

Comment: What is your version of pymongo? I had a memory leak when saving too many documents at a time that was solved by upgrading pymongo, maybe it's somehow related.

Comment: Pymongo 3.0.3. I'm trying to index total_emb_doc for each MyDoc, it will bring down the no. of doc search. Will update if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the db query and serialization. Since we were querying all the MyDoc every time, the performance was affected.
We started maintaining the hash map for `MyDoc id` and `total_emb_doc`. Now we just do one look up and get the Doc.
Currently it is taking 10 seconds for every 10000 entries(with serialization).